# How to enable/disable zooming at runtime?

Tags: android, zooming, android-imageview

I am working on images, I am going to display image in full screen, as user touches on screen then some controls will be shown. So I want to disable zooming when controls are on the screen.

Or somebody tell me how to detect the image is zoom or not?

**activity_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgSelected"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"            
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageControls"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"            
        android:gravity="bottom"  
        android:weightSum="9"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"            
        android:orientation="horizontal"   
        android:visibility="gone"                  
        android:background="@drawable/image_controls">
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnSetAsBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:background="#00000000"
            style="@style/ImageControls"
            android:text="Set"/>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnFavorite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="#00000000"
            style="@style/ImageControls"
            android:text="Favourite"/>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnShare"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:background="#00000000"
            style="@style/ImageControls"
            android:text="Share"/>
    </LinearLayout>        
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_zoom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >
</LinearLayout>
```

**ImageActivity.java**

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity {
private int imageId;
private int categoryId;
private String imageUrl;
private ZoomView zoomView;
private ImageView imageView;
private LinearLayout main_container;
private boolean controlFlag;
private LinearLayout imageControls;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom);             
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);            
    }
    final View convertView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.activity_image, null, false);
    convertView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    imageControls = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageControls);
    controlFlag = false;
    zoomView = new ZoomView(this);
    imageId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("image");
    categoryId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("category");
    imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgSelected);
    imageUrl = SplashActivity.urlList.get(categoryId).get(imageId);
    Log.e(String.valueOf(categoryId),imageUrl);
    Picasso
    .with(this)
    .load(imageUrl)             
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .into(imageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onError() {         

        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);               
        }
    }); 
    zoomView.addView(convertView);
    main_container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_container);
    main_container.addView(zoomView);
    convertView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {          
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {               
            if(controlFlag) {
                imageControls.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                controlFlag = false;
            } else {        
                imageControls.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                controlFlag = true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

I am using android-zoom-view.jar library for zooming. I want to display `LinearLayout (imageControls)` only if image is not zoom Or disable zooming if `LinearLayout (imageControls)` is visible. Because ZoomView instance perform zooming on all over activity so the `imageControls` will also be zoom. This is not a good user friendly design.

So please help me to make this layout better.

Thanks...

Comment: Well in that case you can modify your zoomview class with an extra propety isZoomEnabled and have getter setter for it and set it false when control visible else true. Then in dispatchTouchEvent function in zoomview if isZoomEnabled is false return false else use the current code.

Comment: I am a newbie in android. Can you please specify or can give an example?

Answer (score 2):

In zoomview class thinking you using this https://github.com/Polidea/android-zoom-view/blob/master/src/pl/polidea/view/ZoomView.java 
 just add this

```
boolean isZoomEnable= true;

public void setIsZoomEnable(boolean value){
    isZoomEnable = value;
}
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
    if(!isZoomEnable) return false;
    // single touch
    if (ev.getPointerCount() == 1) {
        processSingleTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    // // double touch
    if (ev.getPointerCount() == 2) {
        processDoubleTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    // redraw
    getRootView().invalidate();
    invalidate();

    return true;
}
```

Then in your code

```
convertView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {          
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {               
        if(controlFlag) {
            imageControls.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            controlFlag = false;
        } else {        
            imageControls.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            controlFlag = true;
        }
        zoomView.setIsZoomEnable(!controlFlag);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: You can directly use the zoomView class directly if you dont want to use jar. check the git link use that class instead of lib.

Comment: can you put the debug point and see is it even going in the dispatchTouchEvent or not when you touch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82486/discussion-between-khan-square-and-nikunj-sakhrelia).